# How to open saved web app using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps

I'm new to PWA (Progressive Web App) and using Angular. I have configured a service worker module as described in the Angular docs. Everything is working fine. On Android, the user is able to add the app to the home screen and it is working on offline as well. But I'm unable to find the functionality to open the saved web app by triggering an action in the browser.

Let's say https://pwa.com is a domain and I want to open saved app (on the home screen) from another domain like https://example.com or from another route on the same domain like https://pwa.com/openApp by clicking on a button. Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is possible for Android: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks

But doesn't seem like it works for iOS
https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7